# Android architecture component room library - How to handle livedata from DAO

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata

I am not clear how to set the live data that is returned from a dao in room. Lets look at a example DAO in room:

```
    @Dao
public interface EventDao {

   @Query("SELECT * FROM " + Event.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + Event.DATE_FIELD + " > :minDate limit 1")
   LiveData<List<Event>> getEvents(LocalDateTime minDate);

   @Insert(onConflict = REPLACE)
   void addEvent(Event event);

   @Delete
   void deleteEvent(Event event);

   @Update(onConflict = REPLACE)
   void updateEvent(Event event);

}
```

In particular, i want to look at the **getEvents** Query call.  It will return a list of events in a liveData object. How is this called from the callers end ?  Anyone have an example with an observable/flowable as well as plain old java ?

Comment: You want to see the implementation of `getEvents` If I am correct, `EventDao` will generat class `EventDao_impl` where every implementation is done. You can look that implementation.

Comment: not sure what you mean still. show me how you would call getEvents ? and show me how you would listen for changes (since im returning a livedata)

Comment: Are you using `ViewModel` or you want to call it directly from activity ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are calling from directly activity then your activity must extends `LifecycleActivity` .

and write below code.

```
db.getEventDao().getEventList().observe(this, new Observer<List<Event>>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(@Nullable List<Event> events) {
        // update your UI.
    }
```

Live data are lifecycle aware. so live data need to know the lifecycle.
So here in `observe` method first argument need the parameter of `LifecycleOwner` which is comes from `LifecycleActivity`.

And if you don't want to use `LifeCycleActivity` then you must have to use `ViewModel`. Prefer this link for more detail https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html

**Note: In current alpha version `LifecycleActivity` is not extending `AppCompatActivity`. In future release it will be part of support library.**